# Error al modificar elementos mediante Jquery

Tags: jquery

El siguiente script detecta en que elemento se hizo y no se hizo clic, pero al intentar modificarlos con Jquery salta error.

```js
    $('body').on('click', '.container-abd a', function(){
        var element = $(this).attr('href');
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var anchors = parent.find('a');
        var notClicked = [];
        anchors.each(function(i, anchor) {
          if($(anchor).attr('href') != element) {
            notClicked.push($(anchor).attr('href'));
          }
        });
        //$(element).fadeIn(1000);
        //$(notClicked).fadeOut(700);
          alert('Se hizo clic en' + element)
          alert('No se hizo clic en' + notClicked)
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container-abd sticky-top">
      <ul>
        <a href="#ebasic-profile">
          <li><i class='bx bx-layer'></i>Basic</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#security">
          <li><i class='bx bx-shield'></i>Security</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#apps">
          <li><i class='bx bxs-zap'></i>Applications</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="ebasic-profile">basic</div>
    <div id="security" style="display:none">security</div>
    <div id="apps" style="display:none">apps</div>
    </body>
```

Comment: ¿Qué error salta? ¿Cuál es el elemento?

Comment: @A.Cedano El elemento que debe desaperecer debe ser en los que no se hizo clic, y debe de aparecer en el que se hizo clic, el código ya se encarga de eso. He modificado el código con un alert para que se aprecie mejor que funciona perfectamente al detectar los elementos, pero al modificarlos salta error.

Answer (score 0):

Lo tienes súper fácil, basta con poner esto dentro del `each`:

```
          $(this).fadeOut(700);
```

Veamos:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.container-abd a', function(){
        var element = $(this).attr('href');
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var anchors = parent.find('a');
        var notClicked = [];
        anchors.each(function(i, anchor) {
          if($(anchor).attr('href') != element) {
              $(this).fadeOut(700);
            //notClicked.push($(anchor).attr('href'));
          }
        });
        //$(element).fadeIn(1000);
        //$(notClicked).fadeOut(700);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container-abd sticky-top">
      <ul>
        <a href="#ebasic-profile">
          <li><i class='bx bx-layer'></i>Basic</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#security">
          <li><i class='bx bx-shield'></i>Security</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#apps">
          <li><i class='bx bxs-zap'></i>Applications</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="ebasic-profile">basic</div>
    <div id="security" style="display:none">security</div>
    <div id="apps" style="display:none">apps</div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, pero creo que no me explique bien, quiero que se realice la animación a los divs que contengan el id en el que se haya hecho clic

Comment: @qwerty entonces entendí mal tu pregunta. En cuanto a la prueba del código en la pregunta no me funciona, más bien me bloquea el navegador.

Comment: Wow, ¿entonces existe otra forma de detectar en que elementos se hizo clic y en cuales no?

Comment: @qwerty ¿cómo así? Yo usé tu misma lógica: `if($(anchor).attr('href') != element) {` ahí, se determina sobre cuáles elementos NO se hizo click y se pueden hacer desaparecer haciendo simplemente esto: `$(this).fadeOut(700);` Eso fue lo que entendí que querías ¿? Cuando hablas de hacer animación a los divs ya me pierdo, no mencionaste nada de divs en la pregunta.

Comment: En la consola me marca: TypeError: elem.ownerDocument is undefined

Comment: ¿Será que habrás cambiando algo @qwerty?  El código funciona perfectamente aquí.